# Include groups not having values with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query to count the calls  :

```
SELECT 
C.CountryCode
,LEFT(CA.Country,2) AS Country
,CA.DateCall
,COUNT(CallID) AS CallsCount
FROM Countries AS C
LEFT JOIN Calls AS CA ON C.CountryCode = LEFT(CA.Country,2)
GROUP BY CountryCode,Country
ORDER BY CallsCount
```

I have the following output :

```
CountryCode Country DateCall     CallsCount
FR          NULL    NULL         0
IT          NULL    NULL         0
GR          GR      13/04/2021   10
SP          SP      18/04/2021   15
```

When I add a condition on the last 7 days :

```
SELECT 
    C.CountryCode
    ,LEFT(CA.Country,2) AS Country
    ,CA.DateCall
    ,COUNT(CallID) AS CallsCount
    FROM Countries AS C
    LEFT JOIN Calls AS CA ON C.CountryCode = LEFT(CA.Country,2)
    WHERE CA.CallDate >=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) 
    GROUP BY CountryCode,Country
    ORDER BY CallsCount
```

This is the output :

```
 CountryCode Country DateCall     CallsCount
 GR          GR      13/04/2021   10
```

While I want to keep all countries having NULL values in the last 7 days :

```
CountryCode Country DateCall     CallsCount
FR          NULL    NULL         0
IT          NULL    NULL         0
GR          GR      13/04/2021   10
SP          NULL    NULL         0
```

Comment: `WHERE CA.CallDate >=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())` makes your `LEFT JOIN` an `INNER JOIN`. The clause *can't* be true if no row was returned from the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT C.CountryCode, LEFT(CA.Country, 2) AS Country, CA.DateCall
       COUNT(CallID) AS CallsCount
FROM Countries C LEFT JOIN
     Calls CA
     ON C.CountryCode = LEFT(CA.Country, 2) AND
        CA.CallDate >=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY C.CountryCode, LEFT(CA.Country, 2)
ORDER BY CallsCount;
```

Your `WHERE` clause filters out `NULL` values -- which is why you are losing rows.

I'm not sure why you have the `LEFT(CA.Country, 2)` in the `SELECT` list.  If there is a match, then it is the same as the first column.  I would suggest removing it.